# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it - using Socket or TcpClient

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, tcpclient

Many people have this same problem, but everyone's implementation is different.

I need help with my implementation of it.

```
void sendUsingTcp() 
{
    try 
    {
        Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(172.16.8.200), 8000);
        sock.Connect(endPoint);
        // code past this never hits because the line above fails
    } 
    catch (SocketException err) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
    }
}
```

I have also tried the TCP Client directly with the same error results:

```
void sendUsingTcp() 
{
    try 
    {
        using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient()) 
        {
            IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(172.16.8.200), 8000);
            client.Connect(endPoint);
            // code past this never hits because the line above fails
        }
    } 
    catch (SocketException err) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
    }
}
```

The IP Address of my PC is `172.16.11.144`.

Comment: It looks like nothing is listening on port `8000` of `172.16.8.200`. Did you actually start a server process there?

Comment: Can you telnet to 172.16.8.200 on port 8000?

Comment: `> telnet 172.16.8.200 <CR>` results in me getting a login prompt. Is this why my code is failing? Because I don't have the login credentials?

Comment: Otherwise, info on how exactly to telnet on port 8000 would be helpful.

Comment: If I understand telnet correctly, that *is* a TCP connection. You'd need to have one for the destination machine to reply asking for a login. It appears from your question that what's happening is that this isn't even getting started. Telnet would probably throw a snotty error message if it found the same thing.

Comment: Refs **AcpMessenger.AcpMessage**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i) it's quite possible that port 8000 is used for something else. Pick another (large) number and see whether the same thing occurs
ii) use the loopback address to connect to your own machine - `IPAddress.Loopback`

Comment: Tom, my application is installed on about 50 different PCs here at work, and they all try to talk back to the same server on Port 8000. Would this be causing the problem? And, if so, how would I fix it?

Comment: Ah. I misunderstood your initial problem. I have only a small amount of experience using .Net tcp connections. Are you able to modify the server code? I assume you're using a `TCPListener` to receive connections; when this is started, try calling `Start(int)` to tell it explicitly the maximum number of connections permitted.

Comment: Darned overloads. If the code compiles and works well in the test scenario, I never think to look into alternate implementations. Marked as answer.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you confirm a resolution to the problem? That is, verifying that it wasn't doing what you wanted it to because of the above, and changing it fixes the problem? I'd be faintly surprised if so, because I would have (naievely) assumed that the default behaviour (i.e. the no-parameter overload you were using) would be to keep accepting new connections until the host machine explodes.

Comment: No, it did not. I will, however, mark the most helpful response as my answer if I never receive a resolution. This encourages others to offer suggestions.

Answer (score 9):

For me it turned out, my Server was listening for incoming connections only from the same IP. I had to change the code for it to listen from any IP.

**Before** and Wrong:

```
IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(172.16.8.200), 8000);
```

**After** with problem fixed:

```
IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked to make sure port 8000 is open on the remote machine? If so, it could be a firewall issue or even something with the network. More details about what's running on the remote machine would help.

Comment: I was just about to ask what is listening on port 8000 on the target machine

Comment: I have an app that I wrote on the server `172.16.8.200` that is actively listening on port 8000. If you know how to check this, I'd like to know.

Comment: cmd `netstat -anb` That's how you check it.

Answer (score 1):

Commonly the problem is that the port is closed. Nothing is listening on the other side.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this was ever answered properly BUT you cannot use a TCPClient to set up a listener - you need a TCPListener class - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Otherwise, you just get an exception when the TCP handshake fails.

Comment: Thanks, Ken. The TCPListener was installed on the Server. 7 year old question. I don't even work at that company anymore. :)